# View display is not what I expect when using react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, jsx

I'm reading **Learning React Native by Bonnie Eisenman** and am having trouble with the WeatherProject tutorial in chapter 3. When the app loads in the iOS simulator, it appears to be rendering the contents of Forecast.js but taking up the whole display without anything from WeatherProject.js

Here is my code:

index.ios.js

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
} from 'react-native';

import WeatherProject from './WeatherProject';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('WeatherProject', () => WeatherProject);
```

WeatherProject.js

```
import React, {
    Component,
} from 'react';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

var Forecast = require('./Forecast');

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#4D4D4D'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  input: {
    fontSize: 20,
    borderWidth: 2,
    height: 40
  }
});

var WeatherProject = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      zip: '',
      forecast: {
        main: 'Clouds',
        description: 'few clouds',
        temp: 45.7
      }
    }
  },

  _handleTextChange(event) {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.text);
    this.setState({
      zip: event.nativeEvent.text
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          You input {this.state.zip}.
        </Text>
        <Forecast
          main={this.state.forecast.main}
          description={this.state.forecast.description}
          temp={this.state.forecast.temp}/>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          returnKeyType="go"
          onSubmitEditing={this._handleTextChange}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = WeatherProject;
```

Forecast.js

```
import React, {
    Component,
} from 'react';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigText: {
    flex: 2,
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  mainText: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  }
});

var Forecast = React.createClass({

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.bigText}>
            {this.props.main}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.mainText}>
            Current conditions: {this.props.description}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.bigText}>
            {this.props.temp}°F
          </Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Forecast;
```

The expected outcome looks like this (from the book):

[image: Expected outcome]

But my actual outcome is this:

[image: Actual outcome]

And here is the view debug hierarchy:

[image]

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style in Forecast:

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center'
}
```

then add the style into the View:

```
<View styles={style.container}>
```

Comment: That sort of worked. It brought the other text into view but the spacing is still all wrong. I tried removing all flex rules from Forecast.js which seems to do the trick but I can't seem to tap into my text input field at all.

Comment: You basically should be putting everything into view containers to help layout your page, so wrap a view around both the Text and TextInput.

Comment: Ok I will give that a try. Thank you for your help. I'll come back to this when I have it working.

Comment: Ok, sorry I thought the forecast component was going to be a modal so my answer isn't exactly what you were looking for.